# Launching Internet Explorer 9 with Developer Tools

Tags: console, internet-explorer-9, developer-tools

I have a script that runs in a browser add-on. It's using the log function of the console object that is only available when the F12 Developer Tools is loaded.

While I can disable the add-on and enable it again to see the early messages intended to be logged, I find it a bit annoying. Is there a way to load IE9 with developer tools? I'm hoping there might be an obscure argument to be passed to the application to enable that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IE10, if you leave the Developer tool pinned to the browser window, it will be loaded  the next time you open Internet Explorer after you exit.

Note that this will not work if it is unpinned.

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible, I would assume it would be mapped to a command-line options, however there doesn't appear to be any such option (though it would be a nice addition to the browser). A current list of all command line options can be found online at [Windows Internet Explorer Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).